# pycord RuntimeError while trying to start ipc Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ipc, pycord

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAepDSxawVE) tutorial to create a discord bot with a dashboard
but when I run my bot.py file I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

**bot.py**:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, ipc


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.ipc = ipc.Server(self,secret_key = "test")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot is ready.")

    async def on_ipc_ready(self):
        print("Ipc server is ready.")

    async def on_ipc_error(self, endpoint, error):
        print(endpoint, "raised", error)


bot_client = Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.default())


@bot_client.ipc.route()
async def get_guild_count(data):
    return len(my_bot.guilds) # returns the len of the guilds to the client

@bot_client.ipc.route()
async def get_guild_ids(data):
    final = []
    for guild in my_bot.guilds:
        final.append(guild.id)
    return final # returns the guild ids to the client


@bot_client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi")

bot_client.ipc.start()
bot_client.run("TOKEN")
```

This is the error I get when running `bot.py`:

```py
  File "D:/PyCharm Projects/AiChat/bot.py", line 44, in <module>
    bot_client.ipc.start()
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\AiChat\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\ipc\server.py", line 253, in start
    self.bot.dispatch("ipc_ready")
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\AiChat\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1281, in dispatch
    super().dispatch(event_name, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\AiChat\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 440, in dispatch
    self._schedule_event(coro, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\AiChat\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 400, in _schedule_event
    return asyncio.create_task(wrapped, name=f"pycord: {event_name}")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client._run_event' was never awaited

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński im using python 3.8

Comment: https://github.com/Ext-Creators/discord-ext-ipc the project is no longer being maintained.

Comment: According to the error this seems to me like a missing `await` somewhere

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use ipc? You could make a simple http api in the bot, and then call that from your dashboard webpage.

Comment: i dont think you need "bot_client.ipc.start()"

Comment: What version are you on? I copy pasted your code only changing the token, and it worked. (python 3.9.6, discordpy 1.7.3)

Comment: ext-ipc is not compatible with dpy 2.0 which is what pycord is forked from. Ideally you should be using the official dpy 2.0 lib rather than the fork.
There have been a lot of async changes in 2.0 recently, which I assume pycord have also merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i **found a solution** and i wanted to help everyone who is stuck on this Problem too. :)

Just simply remove the

```py
async def on_ipc_ready(self):
        print("Ipc server is ready.")
```

part and it should work.

For more information you can [read this issue](https://github.com/Ext-Creators/discord-ext-ipc/issues/47), thats where i got the solution from and it worked for me. Hope i could help some of yall! >:)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have `bot_client.ipc.start()`.

There's an easier way than that, without needing `ipc`. `commands.Bot` has a better way to do that with `event` listeners:

```
import discord
from discord import commands
bot_client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.All())

guildCount = 0
guildIds = []
@bot_client.event
async def on_ready():
    guildCount = len(bot_client.guilds)
    for guild in bot_client.guilds:
        guildIds.append(guild.id)
```

You don't need to use `ipc.start()` for this one. In fact, you don't need `ipc` at all for this one.

There are many more event listeners, you can check them out [in the Discord API reference.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)
:)

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Intents.All() is probably unnecessary but I like to enable them all so my bot gets the permissions it needs to function properly without getting errors.

Comment: Other than the misspelling :) there's nothing wrong with that, but you need to define the extra intent in your developer portal as well. You probably shouldn't add the intent if you don't want to use it, because privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the youtube video you provided and it seems to be outdated (1year old is a lot, try using the wocs instead even tho its arguably harder). I've never seen ipc in use and you can call your own functions regardless of pycord being asychronous. Only if you need to await a function in your own function, use the async keyword before your function and await it itself.